Splitting [tag:regional] further?
Would it make sense to subdivide further regional, for instance into tags for Northern, Central and Southern Italian (and Swiss-Italian if the need arises)? It feels like in many cases OP already knows which of these variants applies.

I think it would be interesting to explain the reason of the downvote.

I really don't know because I'm not Italian and, unfortunately, I don't know very much about this subject, but it seems to me that this post claims that it's not so easy to make such a distinction.

@Charo Downvotes in Meta just mean "I disagree", from what I understand. I don't think it needs an explanation.

I personally do not think it is necessary. We do not have enough questions with the regional tag to justify splitting it. Remember: to justify splitting a tag we not only need that the subject admits a natural division of the topic, but also that there are enough question in each of the subcategories to justify a separate tag.

We have 131 questions with the tag, as I am writing. It's the 10th more common tag on this site, sorting by number of questions. More than [tag:etymology], [tag:adjectives], and [tag:prepositions].
